# LINQ To DataSet from SQL

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-dataset

I am having trouble converting a SQL Join statement into LINQ to DataSet. Also, consider that there will be other tables in the LINQ statement that the Header table will be joined to. Below is my Join statement - any help is appreciated.

```
FROM Header
LEFT JOIN Address
ON Header.Customer = Address.Customer
AND Header.Company = Address.Company
AND ((Header.ShipTo = 'TEMP' AND Header.DocNum = Address.ShipTo) 
    OR Header.ShipTo <> 'TEMP' AND Header.ShipTo = Address.ShipTo)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing a join in Linq uses the `Equals()` method. When using multiple columns, you'll have to create an identically structured anonymous type for comparison.

```
from h in db.header
join a in db.address
on new { 
         cust = h.Customer, 
         comp = h.Company 
       } 
equals new 
       { 
         cust = a.Customer, 
         comp = a.Company 
       }
where ((h.ShipTo == "TEMP" && h.DocNum == a.ShipTo) 
        || h.ShipTo != "TEMP" && h.ShipTo == a.ShipTo)
select h;
```

Comment: THank you, sir! I will also add that later on this particular Join may need to be a left join (shiptos may not be present) and there are other tables joined in this LINQ statement, so is there a way to have the WHERE clause only affect the join statement above and not the joins with the other tables?

Comment: I was able to do a left outer join by taking out the where clause and adding it to join statement. I then just joined header table to the address table twice, once for each each scenario in the where clause.